# How to upload a file from an android application into the tomcat 6 server

Tags: android, jakarta-ee, file-upload, tomcat6

Help me please I have searched and searched but I have not found an operational code,
a code that allows to upload a file from my android application to my Tomcat server 6,

I need the code on the client side and server side. thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

For the Server check out:

[file upload "multipart/form" Exception org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458453/file-upload-multipart-form-exception-org-apache-commons-fileupload-fileuploadb)

And the client:

[Android file uploader with server-side php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204476/android-file-uploader-with-server-side-php)

You should be able to adapt the code from these posts.

Good luck.

Comment: here I have tested the upload with a JSP page in the server but it appears to me the following error:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: \data\data\com.main\files\images.jpg (Le chemin d'accès spécifié est introuvable)

I wonder how he will access the phone to retrieve the photo?

Comment: @Zombie_Colonel would you be more specific, are you saying the jsp code thew an exception?  Please provide a stack trace along with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a web service on your Tomcat server. You can do this using java servlets, php, or a WCF service in. NET.  Then access your web service using a RESTful client

Comment: Yes i know and i want to use java servlets, in fact i posted this topic for having the code directly if somebody already made why the remake ?